# How to measure rate in telegraf using hot-shots

Tags: average, monitoring, mean, telegraf, gauge

I am using [hot-shots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-shots) module in Node to send measurements to telegraf, which then sends data to influx db. I want to measure exact cache hit rate. My collection interval is 1s. I use `gauge` to store these measurements where value 0 is cache miss, value 1 is cache hit. However, this `gauge` is often called multiple times during the collection interval and only the last value is stored and sent to influx (the previous ones are overwritten). I am losing a lot of measurement data this way and the resulting cache hit rate displayed in Grafana is imprecise. I need to see averaged values of ALL gauge measurements that occured. I am considering using `increment` with tags `cache-hit` and `cache-miss` because these measurements are accumulated during the collection interval. I will not lose data this way, but it feels really dumb (I understand `gauge` is probably dumb as well).

How can I achieve this in an easy and understandable way ?